# C++ Faulty Random Numbers

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I'm creating a machine that generates a shotgun with random components that effect the overall quality of the gun. I'm having a problem generating the random parts that will comprise the shotgun. There are 4 parts that have to be generated. When I created each of these functions, I tested them individually and they all work but when I try to put them together with the `createChromo()` function, the numbers are individually random. I should be getting results like 2131 and 1332, but I keep getting 1111 or 1112 or 2221 or 2222....Here is the code:

```
int generateButt()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int buttType = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if(buttType == 1)
    {
         accuracy = rand() % ((5 - 2) + 2) / 10.0;

         fireRate = fireRate - 0.3;
    }
    if(buttType == 2)
    {
        accuracy = rand() % ((8 + 5) + 5)/ 10.0;

        fireRate = fireRate - 0.2;
    }
    if(buttType == 3)
    {
        accuracy = rand() % ((11 + 8) + 8) / 10.0;

        fireRate = fireRate - 0.1;
    }

    return buttType;
}
int generateBarrel()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int barrelType = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if(barrelType == 1)
    {
        range = rand() % (16 - 5) + 5;

        power = power + 3;
    }
    if(barrelType == 2)
    {
        range = rand() % (21 - 16) + 16;

        power = power + 1;
    }
    if(barrelType == 3)
    {
        range = rand() % (26 + 21) + 21;

        power = power - 1;
    }

    return barrelType;
}
int generateBullet()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int bulletType = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if(bulletType == 1)
    {
        power = rand() % (16 - 10) + 10;

        range = range + 5;
    }
    if(bulletType == 2)
    {
        power = rand() % (26 - 16) + 16;

        range = range + 1;
    }
    if(bulletType == 3)
    {
        power = rand() % (35 - 26) + 26;

        range = range - 2;
    }

    return bulletType;
}
int generateAction()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int actionType = rand() % 2 + 1;

    if(actionType == 1)
    {
        fireRate = 1.5;

        accuracy = accuracy + 0.2;
    }
    if(actionType == 2)
    {
        fireRate = 2.0;

        accuracy = accuracy - 0.1;
    }

    return actionType;
}

void createChromo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    cout <<a<<b<<c<<d<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
        for(int i = 0; i < popSize; i++)
        createChromo(generateButt(), generateBarrel(), generateBullet(), generateAction());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be calling `srand` **once**.

Comment: @chris - you should make that the answer that the random sequence is not seeded - funny enough this was an inspection issue on a colleges code today :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish, Seemed a bit weeny, but yeah, I guess.

Comment: Also the code here tries to produce several different distributions manually and would really benefit from the C++ `<random>` library built-in distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `srand` each time you call either function. What `srand` does is seed the generator for a new string of random numbers. You base that seed off of the current second, so if it's called in the same second, the seed will be the same as last time, and thus the sequence of random numbers obtained from `rand()` will be as well.

Call `srand(time(NULL));` once at the beginning of your program to just have one sequence, and keep using the next number in that one sequence instead of starting the same sequence over.

If you have access to C++11, you might consider using the `<random>` header as well.

Comment: thank you, removing the excess calls to `srand(time(NULL))` helped

Comment: @Scott, And cut down the size :) I'd really recommend looking into the header sometime if you can, though, as the features offered in it are much vaster and better than the stuff we got from C.

Answer (score 1):

1. the concept of *random* does not exist in the entire computation world
2. the function `srand()` is used to set a seed for the `rand()` function
3. if you set 2 different seed your generator of pseudo-random numbers will behave in 2 different ways

Comment: @SethCarnegie how ? where ? when ?

Comment: You can get use physical devices to get data which is truly random.

Comment: @SethCarnegie this is a big error, analogic data also generates infinite variations and is impossible to read from physical device in a way that you can preserve all the data because the computation world is finite and the physical world it's not. Also i was writing about the computation world, not the physical world.

Comment: Yes, the physical devices can give truly random *input* to a computation process, but cannot really be a part of it...

Comment: @axis It doesn't matter how much you preserve, a single bit is enough to be random. Also I don't really know what definition we are using for "computational world" so I can't respond to the second part.

Comment: @MarkusSaers this is not about computation ... also there are other big problems about that, one of them is ensuring that you have a good input, good luck with keeping the noise low and having the noise not affecting your _input_

Comment: Umm... I thought the whole line of comments were precisely about computation, and computations are, by definition, always deterministic. No room for any chance at all, some answer every time for the same input. I thought it was obvious that having a physical device generating random input to computer was ridiculous, but since that did not get through, I'll state it explicitly.

Comment: The entropy contained in a single bit is enough to generate two distinct lines of pseudo-random numbers. That is: every time you run the program you will get one of two outcomes. I doubt that is sufficient for most application where randomness is needed.

Comment: @MarkusSaers having a physical device producing random input is not ridiculous, google on their websites uses mouse movement for seeding their random number generators.